# My <% %> not working in div. Why?

Tags: asp.net

I've tried both snippets below. Nothing. I've tried <%#, <%=, and <%. Nothing. So I'm stuck.

```
<div style="background-color:Gray; color:white; text-align:center; width:100%;">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank"  NavigateUrl='<%= Server.HtmlEncode(String.Format("~/ShowHistory.aspx?section={0}&jobnumber={1}", "APQP Header", "101244")) %>' runat="server">Show Updated History</asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="~/ShowDeletedHistory.aspx" ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">Show Deleted History</asp:HyperLink></div>
        <br />

<div style="background-color:Gray; color:white; text-align:center; width:100%;">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank"  NavigateUrl='<%= String.Format("~/ShowHistory.aspx?section={0}&jobnumber={1}", "APQP Header", "101244") %>' runat="server">Show Updated History</asp:HyperLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="~/ShowDeletedHistory.aspx" ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">Show Deleted History</asp:HyperLink></div>
        <br />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no working"?

Comment: I mean instead of the hyperlink working as it should, it's just text. I look at the source and get this: <div style="background-color:Gray; color:white; text-align:center; width:100%;">
                <a id="HyperLink1" href="&lt;%=%20Server.HtmlEncode(String.Format(&quot;~/ShowHistory.aspx?section={0}&amp;jobnumber={1}&quot;, &quot;APQP Header&quot;, &quot;101244&quot;)) %>" target="_blank">Show Updated History</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a id="HyperLink2" href="ShowDeletedHistory.aspx" target="_blank">Show Deleted History</a></div>
            <br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server controls cannot contain this type of tags. The reason is that "<%= %>" is [basically equal to Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5(VS.71).aspx), which itself executes after the page has gone through its lifecycle, when the response is already constructed. If you use it when setting a value of a server-side control property, this value has to be resolved when (or a little after) parsing the page markup. This is the reason you cannot use "<%= %>" in a server control.

If it was a normal html tag, it would work, but the virtual URL would not.

Is there a reason you're not setting the NavigationUrl in code? It would look much nicer to me.

Comment: Putting the URL in code-behind worked. Although, I had to put in LoadComplete event instead of the Load event. I have the Control Toolkit in my page. And somehow when I had the Navigation URL in Page_Load, the event did not fire and the URL didn't load. But when I put them in Page_LoadComplete, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try `<%# ... %>` and call `this.DataBind()` (or `Me.DataBind()`) when your page loads.

Comment: This worked. But it broke the textChanged Event I was using. So I used the solution below.